# insserv: loop involving firewall and monit

Tags: debian

I'm unable to install anything and remove anything due to this

```
insserv: warning: script 'firewall' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: There is a loop between service monit and firewall if stopped
insserv:  loop involving service firewall at depth 2
insserv:  loop involving service monit at depth 1
insserv: Stopping firewall depends on monit and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: exiting now without changing boot order!
```

What ?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your `/etc/init.d/firewall` script (which isn't in Debian, so we can't check) is broken with respect to dependency-based boot ordering. For a firewall, I'd recommend an LSB header like this:

```
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          firewall
# Required-Start:    $local_fs
# Required-Stop:     $local_fs
# X-Start-Before:    networking
# Default-Start:     S
# Default-Stop:
# Short-Description: Start firewall
### END INIT INFO
```

(assuming its startup does not require DNS resolution being available).

Comment: Thanks, this helped me fix the problem as the script I was using didn't have any of those comments

Answer (score 1):

I stopped both `monit` and `firewall` services. Firewall init.d script was not part of debian. Was a custom script, I didn't notice this.

I moved `firewall` init.d script out, to a temp folder.

Then I was able to uninstall `monit`.

At end, I restored init.d script for `firewall`.